# Use UILabel in Class Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uilabel

So I have this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UILabel *Screen;
}

+(void)num:(int)number;
```

And I want to access Screen in another class in the num method like so:

```
+(void)num:(int)number{
    Screen.text = @"test";
}
```

But xCode says

> "Instance variable 'Screen' accesses in class method"

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does it have to be a class method? I.e. can you change the + to - ?

Comment: You can't use non static member in static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the reason it is not letting you is because the + sign in the method denotes a class method aka to be called on ViewController class but you don't have a reference to your specific Screen outlet.

Change the + to a - and then you will be able to call the method like

```
[self num:7]
```

and access the Screen outlet in that method

Hope that helps!

Comment: No prob @Andrew ! Glad I could help

Answer (score -2):

You can do this if your ViewController is singleton. You have to store pointer to your viewcontroller and then you can access to its variables.

For a example:

(h file)

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UILabel *Screen;
}

+(void)num:(int)number;
```

(m file)

```
+(ViewController*)instance
{
    static ViewController *inst = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        inst = [ViewController new];
    });

    return inst;
}

+(void)num:(int)number{
    [ViewController instance]->Screen.text = @"test";
}
```

Comment: or if you ViewController isn't singleton you have to to change "+" to "-" in method declaration :)